# Windows Firefox Security Exception Window resizing itself

Tags: windows-10, firefox, resizing

When manually adding a security exception in Firefox the pop-up window resizes itself to a slightly larger size if you click the "get-certificate" button. The issue is that this size becomes permanent and the window cannot be resized manually. This effect is cumulative, and even after the window is closed the next time it opens it does so at the new size.

Manually accepting security exceptions is a regular thing for me and this window has now been resized to the point that I cannot see it in its entirety. Alt-Spacebar resizing attempts to move, not resize, so it doesn't help.

I am not an administrator on this system, so I can not start Firefox with any elevated privileges

How can I either resize this window manually, or restore the window to its default size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is acknowledged by Firefox and is tracked by bug

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> - Access a site with an unsigned certificate
> - Your connection is not secure > Advanced > Add exception
> - Click the "Get Certificate" button multiple times
>
> Actual results:
>
> - Window "Add Security Exception" size increased.
> - Size stays the same even after the browser is restarted.
> - If you click the button too much, you are unable to add exceptions, as the size is bigger than your window.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1441304.

Update:
The original Firefox bug used to track the issue is: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424311.

The issue is fixed in Firefox release 60, so upgrade the Firefox once the release is available.

Comment: In the future, link-only answers will be downvoted as being unhelpful.  I have not taken the effort to actually confirm, a bug report confirmed to be a problem on the current version of Firefox, is a problem on the build the author was using in 2017.  However, I see the potential relevance of such a bug report.  In the future **I** won't go to the effort of making **your** answers helpful.  Link-only answers are typically downvoted and eventually deleted by the community.

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, Thanks for editing the post. I will take care of points you mentioned in future. Thanks.

Comment: This issue was resolved later-on in a large update for Firefox (that seemed to make some other issues involving certificates appear that are far more detrimental to my old company's usage of certificates).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me with FF 56.0 on Windows 10.  Start Firefox in an elevated mode. With the security exception popup in focus, press Alt-Space and choose the Size option.  Next, press either left arrow or right arrow key to resize horizontally, or up arrow or down arrow key to resize vertically.  Press both to resize diagonally.  Now move the mouse and the resize will be controlled by the mouse.  Left click the mouse button to keep the new size or ESC to cancel.  Note that there is a minimum size that FF refuses to go down further.

Comment: I am not an administrator on this system so elevated mode is not possible, and the Alt-Space option is not working. I won't downvote this answer because it is the normal method, but I did state that Alt-Space resizing attempts do not work. It defaults to move instead of resize.

Comment: Will edit to add that I am not an administrator and do not have access to elevated mode.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this again, I've asked it on the Mozilla support and got an answer. It's quite easy.

> Try to rename/remove xulstore.json and if present delete localstore.rdf in the Firefox profile folder with Firefox closed.
> You can use the button on the "Help -> Troubleshooting Information" (about:support) page to go to the current Firefox profile folder or use the about:profiles page. 
> Help -> Troubleshooting Information -> Profile Directory: 
> Windows: Show Folder; 
> Linux: Open Directory; 
> Mac: Show in Finder

https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/1207294

Answer (score 1):

If the security exception window is still too large after the update to FF60+, it can be changed as follows:

1. open xulstore.json (see answer by @OCarinha on how to find the file)
2. find `chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul`
3. decrease the value for "height", and save the file again.

For me this entry looked like this, and was larger than my screen:

```json
"chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul": {
    "exceptiondialog": {
        "screenX": "437",
        "screenY": "8",
        "width": "869",
        "height": "1100"
    }
}
```

After setting height to a smaller value, the exception dialogue again looks as expected.